# Complete Germany city database with cities, villages and regions

Tags: data-request, city, database, geocoding, germany

I am looking for a very detailed free or not free city database for Germany. I need information like state or village, region, latitude, and longitude, and population. I think Geonames is a bit messy and not very clean.

Comment: geonames is the default for these types of questions. Can you provide some examples where the data isn't clean enough?

Comment: How about Openstreetmap?  I think Germany is one of the most complete countries on Openstreetmap.

Comment: @gerrit - would work if `key:population` has good coverage https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:population

Comment: There is also [wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org).  Not an answer because I don't know about the quality or coverage.  It would make sense for wikidata and openstreetmap to cooperate, no clue if they do though.

Comment: I was found in the past a site with the cities of all countries, where you can buy a license of the files. I was working 4 years ago on the geonames data and on some places it was wrong. But yes, this is maybe the only one detailed source.

Answer (score 0):

1. Scrape place names from google maps
2. Manually enter pop for large cities and ignore the rest or impute  based on nearby cities
3. Lat long from google
4. Once you have name and location  and nearby city pop then manually enter  or impute the rest